# Does the value 5 in both the variable and the Array is allocated with same memory location in the below program?

Tags: java, memory, allocation

In the below code how (x==val), I mean does the value of val(i.e. 5) and the 5th element of the array (i.e. 5 )has same memory location.

```
class Search {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int nums[] = { 6, 8, 3, 7, 5, 6, 1, 4 };     
        int val = 5;  
        boolean found = false;     
        for(int x : nums) {  
            if(x == val) {   
                found = true;  
                break;       
            }
        } 
        if (found)      
            System.out.println("Value found!");   
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they are not for the example you listed.

If these were object references and the "Value found!" message was printed then yes because for reference types the "==" operation checks whether the references are equal, i.e. whether they point to the same object. However for primitive types (such as an int) the "==" operation simply checks whether the values are equal (and not whether or not they are the same memory location).

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't. In your example, the array reserves a contiguous segment of memory, while the variable `val` is reserved in a different location. Even if both elements (i.e. `val` and the `nth` element of an array) have the same value, they are stored in different locations.

To see the effect of that yourself, try changing the value of one of them. You'll find that the other variable still holds its value. It's like two persons having the same name, this doesn't make them the same person.